# Get the three latest time json elements

Tags: json, linq, c#-4.0

I have a json array. The element format is likely below:

```
{
    "CKey": "S2_123_45_20130416105655",
    "TimeOfCall": "2013-04-17T06:00:00-04:00",
    "DestinationNumber": "123456789",
    "CallType": "X",
    "CardNumber": ""
}
```

There are many elements in the array, I only want the latest three order by `TimeOfCall(DateTime format)` within 24 hrs. They may be nothing or 1,2. The maximum is 3.
Original I thought using several dictionaries to store and sort by the value but it is too complicated.

**UPDATE:**

This json array was from a json string by the C# code:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<CallDataDTO>));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response4.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
calls = (List<CallDataDTO>)ser.ReadObject(ms); // dynamic
jsonStr4 = _dynamicConvert.DynamicToString(calls);// convert dynamic to string
jsonArray4 = JArray.Parse(jsonStr4); // convert string to a json array.
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
?jsonArray4
{[
   {
    "CKey": "P2_123_23_20130416105655",
    "TimeOfCall": "2013-04-17T06:00:00-04:00",
    "DestinationNumber": "1234567890",
    "CallType": "DEBIT",
    "CardNumber": ""
 },
 {
"CKey": "P5_123_105_20130412154035",
"TimeOfCall": "2013-04-17T07:00:00-04:00",
"DestinationNumber": "1234567890",
"CallType": "DEBIT",
"CardNumber": ""
},
{
  "CKey": "P5_123_114_20130412154000",
  "TimeOfCall": "2013-04-07T08:00:00-04:00",
  "DestinationNumber": "1234567890",
  "CallType": "DEBIT",
  "CardNumber": ""
}
]}
base {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer}: {[
{
  "CKey": "P2_123_23_20130416105655",
  "TimeOfCall": "2013-04-17T06:00:00-04:00",
  "DestinationNumber": "1234567890",
  "CallType": "DEBIT",
  "CardNumber": ""
},
{
  "CKey": "P5_123_105_20130412154035",
  "TimeOfCall": "2013-04-17T07:00:00-04:00",
  "DestinationNumber": "1234567890",
  "CallType": "DEBIT",
  "CardNumber": ""
},
{
 "CKey": "P5_123_114_20130412154000",
 "TimeOfCall": "2013-04-07T08:00:00-04:00",
 "DestinationNumber": "1234567890",
 "CallType": "DEBIT",
 "CardNumber": ""
}
]}
 Type: Array
```

Comment: How often do you want to do this? If it's infrequently, then just sort the array and pick the top 3. Otherwise, give us a little more information about your data structures and how they're used.

Comment: It is infrequently to do it, I don't know how to sort entire object. Should I create dictionaries?

Comment: Is this an array of objects? Or a JSON document? What are your data structures?

Comment: See my updated, maybe I did a wrong way to convert the string to a json array.

Comment: Post the whole Json text as well (the whole array, not just an item)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like

```
jsonArray4.Where(item => Convert.ToDateTime(item["TimeOfCall"]).Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
.OrderByDescending(item => Convert.ToDateTime(item["TimeOfCall"]))
.Take(3);
```

Update: If you need the last 24 hours instead of the current day than:

```
jsonArray4.Where(item => Convert.ToDateTime(item["TimeOfCall"]) >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24))
.OrderByDescending(item => Convert.ToDateTime(item["TimeOfCall"]))
.Take(3);
```

[Linq to Json](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help)

Update2: What I suggested previously should work. Here is my complete code sample:

```
string jsonText = @"[
{
    'CKey': 'P2_123_23_20130416105655',
    'TimeOfCall': '2013-04-17T06:00:00-04:00',
    'DestinationNumber': '1234567890',
    'CallType': 'DEBIT',
    'CardNumber': ''
},    
{
    'CKey': 'P5_123_105_20130412154035',
    'TimeOfCall': '2013-04-17T07:00:00-04:00',
    'DestinationNumber': '1234567890',
    'CallType': 'DEBIT',
    'CardNumber': ''
},
{
    'CKey': 'P5_123_114_20130412154000',
    'TimeOfCall': '2013-04-07T08:00:00-04:00',
    'DestinationNumber': '1234567890',
    'CallType': 'DEBIT',
    'CardNumber': ''
}    
]";

var result = JArray.Parse(jsonText).
    Where(item => Convert.ToDateTime(item["TimeOfCall"]).Date == new DateTime(2013, 4, 17))
    .OrderByDescending(item => Convert.ToDateTime(item["TimeOfCall"]))
    .Take(3);
```

Note that I have slightly changed the condition to actually return something. If you need results from the last 24 hours only than change the condition to >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)

Comment: To be honest I am not surprised, I don't have the time to actually run the code. However I will once I have the time.

Comment: Thank you, but I think linq can't not be applied a json array directly.

Comment: It can, however it can be that Json.Net's Linq implementation has some restrictions. I will dive deeper into this once I am not this busy.

Comment: Finally I had the time to actually run the code and it works fine (apart from a syntax error due to a typo). I suggest you to review the case.

Comment: What version of Json.Net are you using?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json Runtime Version: v4.0.30319

Comment: You should update to the latest version (5.0.3 at the moment)

Comment: I did it but just no lucky. I don't think it can be resolved at all.